# Why is there conflict between bioinfo.cls and \usepackage{multicols}?

Tags: pdftex, multicol

Why does the behavior listed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180976/bioinfo-cls-leads-to-strange-ignoring-of-header) occur?

Just to recap, the bioinformatics template (available [here](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/bioinformatics/for_authors/bioinfo01.zip) and elsewhere) leads to overwritten headers when used in conjunction with `\usepackage{multicols}`. Why does this happen?

An example of what I am referring to is here:

[image]

Note that this example does *not* contain any usage of the multicol package; its very existence is leading to the conflict.

Just to be clear, I am trying to understand this from the perspective of a LaTeX user; this is not imperative to any particular assignment or paper right now. I want to know the answer in the pursuit of getting better at TeX and LaTeX.

EDIT:

Here is the code for the example above:

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}  % omit 'demo' option from real document
\documentclass{bioinfo}
%\documentclass{article}
\copyrightyear{2014}
\pubyear{2014}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\firstpage{1}

\title[QTL Analysis]{Evaluation of a QTL Dataset}
\author[Robert R. Gotwals]{Robert R. Gotwals\,\footnote{to whom correspondence should be addressed}}
\address{$^{1}$Department of XXXXXXX, Address XXXX etc.}

\history{Received on XXXXX; revised on XXXXX; accepted on XXXXX}
\editor{Gotwals}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

Here's the abstract. 

\section{Keywords:} first, second, third, fourth

%\section{Contact:} \href{cowbell@ncssm.edu}{gotwals@ncssm.edu}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection*{Get funky!}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore. Figure \ref{thrombin} is a display of thrombin. 
It's a long, long story... 
My hard drive was nearly full, and the computer wouldn't boot into Windows anymore.
Had a bunch of problems, MFT corruptions, BSODs, disk read errors...
Nothing worked. Then... in February or so, my sister gave me her old computer to use.
My brother removed all the stuff and reformatted it, and then whilst I was sleeping he put my HDD in sister's computer. The computer was now with two HDDs, and working again. (Mine is a MAXTOR and hers a Samsung)
About two days later I was prompted with a BSOD, about software. Looking up on Google (with an old machine) I find a solution but it would mean all my program settings would be deleted, or changed. Didn't care. So I did what was written on the article. Don't remember what happened next, but I know for sure that some programs wouldn't work, or had issues, including the antivirus (avast!), which would give me an error every hour or so. 
There wasn't a way to reinstall, it failed. So I just installed Avira. Stayed with it for some time until I noticed the sound was slowing down randomly, and chopping. I updated the audio drivers but it didn't work. Then I tried a number of things, but no luck. I uninstalled Avira (which was also giving me some errors), and the sound kind of improved, but it was still bad.
Whatever...
The Samsung hard drive also kept disappearing, both from Windows and BIOS, so anything stored on it wouldn't be accessible anymore. It would also make the dreaded clicking noise.

\subsection*{What ever }

Now the most recent stuff... and what is bugging me... this Saturday I was playing some games installed on my sister's hard drive. It was all okay until a clicking noise appeared. The game froze. That happened for a while until a BSOD came, which made me turn off the computer. I immediately thought the HDD was horrible and untrusted, or that a cable was loose.
The computer kept giving me a BSOD.
Left it alone for some time.
Midnight comes, I try starting up the computer, and the click strikes again. But this time with my HDD.
The BSOD was either there, or NTLDR failure, or the drive simply wouldn't be recognised.
It was probably dead, and there was nothing I could do to help.
I got to bed.
Waking up, mum says my computer is faster than ever. 
That was strange, since it was very slow before. But who cares, the hard drive wasn't dead after all. Or so I thought.
Turns out my brother had formatted the Samsung drive (sister's) without telling me, or asking for permission.
Everything that I had was lost, or at least missing.
I then took a peek and Windows said my drive had:
232 GBs of 232 GBs total.
I am now hopeless. I am pretty sure I lost everything, but perhaps there is a small chance of recovering my data. Never made any backups, since there was no way to. I don't have any external drives with me, and the computers we have available have very small capacity. 
It was over 200 GB of data. Everything was important to me. I had thousands and thousands of folders. It would take a long time to search and copy the files.
My mum who knows nothing about computers, told me it might be empty because it's borked. But she also doesn't believe that my stuff is missing.
I can access it fine without any errors. I don't want to put anything there, though, in fears of (hidden) data getting overwritten. All my fault, I'm 

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{Thrombin.png}
\caption{Thrombin}
\label{thrombin}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: add a minimal selfcontained document that shows the behavior not just a screen shot please

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your MWE minimally so that it becomes compilable for people who don't have the file `Thrombin.png`.

Comment: Not an answer to your question as to the cause of the clearly unfortunate interaction between the `bioinfo` document class and the `multicol` package, but a question back to you: Why would you load the `multicol` package in the first place in the current situation? The `bioinfo` class uses the LaTeX kernel `\twocolumn` command to set things in two columns, hence is going to come from loading the `multicol` package.

Comment: @Mico, I honestly should have known better. I have used LaTeX a decent bit, but am not used to working with stylesheets yet.

Answer (score 9):

That's mighty strange :-)

The reason is this bit of code inside `\maketitle`:

```
\if@twocolumn
  \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
    \@maketitle
  \else
    \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
  \fi
\else
```

which is actually a straight copy from code also found in `article.cls`.

Now `\col@number` is only set (to either 1 or 2) in the LaTeX kernel and the code above is the only place where it is ever used. Took me a while to come up with a reason why that was added in 1994, the change log only says that it got added :-)

As far as I can make out it is there to allow somebody to write

```
\twocolumn[\maketitle]
```

`\twocolumn` sets both `\col@number=2` and  `\@twocolumntrue` but in case of an optional argument it locally sets `\col@number` back to 1. So a `\maketitle` inside the optional argument of `\twocolumn` would just execute `\@maketitle` and not `\twocolumn[\@maketitle]` which would probably be a disaster as it would mean you would get another call to `\twocolumn` inside the `\twocolumn` call.

So far so good, but why does this makes a problem if `multicol` is just loaded?

Simply because that package explicitly sets `\col@number=1` on top-level and that results in the title being set just in the first column (execpt that it is actually a box of full width):

```
%    To allow checking whether some macro is used within the \mc{}
%    environment the counter |\col@number| gets a default of |1|
%    outside the the environment.
% \changes{v1.3d}{1991/10/23}{\cs{col@number} set to one}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\col@number = 1
```

Now that is from 1991 and LaTeX seems to have added `\col@number` in 1994 so I guess one can say it isn't `multicol`s fault. One the other hand I'm quitel likely the one who added it to the kernel or at least didn't complained (knowing that I had it already in `multicol` so either way it is a homegrown issue).

So how to fix? Reapply `\twocolumn` after loading `multicol`, e.g.,

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\twocolumn
```

However, as Mico correctly remarked, what is the purpose of `multicol` inside a two-column document?

One might think that one could use it, e.g.,

[image]

but this only looks like it works ... it will fail miserably the moment the multicol environment exceeds the column size (because then it starts a new page (not a new column)). So all you could use it for would be inside boxes but not really on the main vertical galley.

Perhaps I could update multicol to properly work with `\twocolumn` but I don't really see much applications for it.

### Edit 2016

I finally took the initialization of `\col@number` out so on top-level it will now reflect whatever has been set by LaTeX (i.e., it will work in two-column mode but only in a limited way as explained above (basically if used in a box or only for very short texts)).